# Can't connect to Pocket PC from Windows 7 

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, connection, pocket-pc

I can't connect to Pocket PC from Windows 7. What do I need to install to get it working?

Answer (score 1):

You need [Windows Mobility Center](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-vista/features/mobility-center.aspx) ([download](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsmobile/en-us/downloads/microsoft/device-center-download.mspx)). However, Windows 7 should download it itself once you plug in device.